# Oracle regular expression replacement for negative lookahead/lookbehind

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm writing a **PL/SQL Oracle procedure** that looks for possible customer numbers in a column.  Customer numbers are **7 digits long**, and could be **prefixed or suffixed** with any number of characters. However **some of the values contain > 7 digit numbers**, and in these cases I want to ignore them.  So **"A/C 1234567" and "Cust1234567B"** should return a match for customer number **1234567**, but "**01234567**" and "**123456789**" should not.

I am using `\d{7}` but this is returning a match on all the examples, so am looking for something similar to `(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)` - but negative lookahead and lookbehind aren't supported.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `(?:^|\D)\d{7}(?:\D|$)` ?

Comment: @zerkms: I think you should post that as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without lookahed and lookbehind assertions available you could try

```
(^|\D)\d{7}(\D|$)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12114/0

Comment: Try the following:
SELECT 'Matched' AS RESULT
FROM DUAL
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(' 1234567 ', '(?:^|\D)\d{7}(?:\D|$)');
...does not return Matched

Comment: In my testing I have found it's not returning exactly what I need, e.g. "Cust1234567B" returns "t1234567B".  So I am surrounding it with another REGEXP_SUBSTR such as REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Cust1234567B', '(?:^|\D)\d{7}(?:\D|$)'), '\d{7}') to just pull out the 7 digits.  Is there a way to exclude returning the first and last non-digit characters if they exist in the original?

Comment: @Laurence: it would be if oracle supported `?:` which you as you remember we ought to remove

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, what I did was simply

```
NOT regexp_like(<pattern_you_want_to_negate>)
```