# Oracle regex string not beginning with '40821'

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, regex-negation

I am trying to define a regex that matches string with numbers and it's not begining with 40821, so '40822433598347597' matches and '408211' not. So, I've tried

```
^(?!40821)\d+
```

Works perfectly in my regex editor, but still doesnt work in oracle. I know, it's very easy to use `where not` but my goal is to do it using only regex. Please, some pieces of advice, what am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: do you really need regex for this..you can use `SUBSTR( source_string, 0,4) NOT LIKE '40821'`..not sure if this would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016972/oracle-regular-expression-replacement-for-negative-lookahead-lookbehind), negative lookahead and lookbehind are not supported in Oracle.

One way would be to explicitly enumerate the possibilities using alternation. In your case it would be something like:

```
^([012356789]|4[123456789]|40[012345679]|408[013456789]|4082[023456789])
```

Comment: Not sure if Oracle supports shortcuts like `\d` and `\D`, but if it does this can be shortened to `^([^\D4]|4[^\D0]|40[^\D8]|408[^\D2]|4082[^\D1])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!a)b matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a"
```

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

That kind of Perl's sytax is not supported by Oracle.